# Detecting command + keystroke in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, onkeypress

I'm trying to intercept the command + keystroke in Safari. I've added an event handler as follows:

```
document.onkeypress = handleKeyPress;

function handleKeyPress(event) {
    if ("+" === String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) && event.metaKey) {
        // my code here
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I hit <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> (<kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> is `+` on my US keyboard), the if statement does not return true.

If I remove the event.metaKey portion of the if statement and hit <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>, the if statement does return true.

Also, if I change the matching string from "+" to "=" and hit <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> (with or without the shift key), the if statement does return true.

Is there a way to actually detect the command + keypress (without assuming that the + key is shift = and checking for the event.shiftKey, since this will not be true for some non-US keyboards)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I can't necessarily recommend using ⌘+ as a shortcut, since it already means something in Safari (namely, zoom the page). Someone might want that to still work normally. Depending on what you're building, it might make sense, but don't override the default shortcuts unless you're sure.

Anyway: [Key events are tricky](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html), often because the keyCode/charCode/which properties don't always match up with the right letter, so `String.fromCharCode` won't always get you a proper string. `keyIdentifier` is sometimes a better thing to look at, but not always (for instance, its codes for letter keys are always uppercase letters).

What I've done in the past (and I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it, but it works ok), is to instead listen for keydown and keyup events, and "stack" modifier keys. I.e. whenever a key is depressed, check whether it's a modifier key (i.e. if it's cmd, ctrl, alt, or shift). If it is, add it to the "stack" of modifiers. Do the opposite on keyup; if the released key was a modifier, remove it from the stack.

Now, back in the keydown-handler, if the key wasn't a modifier key, you can send the keydown event (which, unlike a keypress event, will have a pretty reliable `keyIdentifier` property to check), and the stack of modifiers along to some other callback, that'll take it from there.

In your case, such a callback would check that the cmd-key is in the stack, and that the keyIdentifier for the keydown event is "U+002B" (which is the unicode code for `+`).

[I've put together a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7C76W/) of what I'm talking about. If you click in the "Result" pane (to make sure it's got focus), and press ⌘+, it should show the key combo you used, and write "Success!" below. Otherwise, it'll just show the key combo. On my keyboard, the plus sign is directly accessible, so the key combo I see is just "⌘+". But if you need shift to type a plus sign, you should see "⇧⌘+".

It's a generalized piece of code that's good for handling keyboard shortcuts in Safari/Mac, so you can build on it, if you want. You'll want to add a few event listeners to reset the modifier stack on blur events and such. Ideally, the modifier stack would reset automatically, as you release the keys, but since something might cause the browser, or the observed element/window/document, to lose focus, the keyup events won't be handled, and the released keys won't be removed from the stack. So check for blur events.

Comment: First, I agree 100% with being careful hijacking ⌘+. I have a plugin that overrides the built-in zoom commands and recalls zoom level on a per-site basis, so I think it's appropriate in this case. Second, thanks for the answer. I think you've provided all the tools I need to figure out the answer, but I'll take a day to make sure that I can take this info and make it meet my needs.

Comment: Works perfectly... thanks! One minor correction to your jsfiddle example, you have the unicode for the '=' key (U+003D) instead of the '+' key (U+002B) in the exampleCallback function.

Comment: @CeriMorgan: Ah, sorry about that. When I was putting the jsfiddle together, I had misread your question and though you want to listen for ⌘=, not ⌘+. I edited my answer before posting but forgot to edit the jsfiddle. Anyway; great that it code otherwise works

Answer (score 0):

Register the event object in a window object level one, event = window.EE for example, then browse it with Firebug or Safari’s Web Developer Tools and see the values that are triggered when you want. So you will know what to compare against.

Comment: I have compared the whole event object in both cases (command shift = and command =) and the results seem to be exactly the same other than the presence of the shiftKey modifier being present in the former case. However, I don't want to make the assumption that shift = will always be + (I already have one user for whom that's not true).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't think there is an answer.  The problem is, for `CMD+SHIFT+=` the `charCode` being pressed is 61 (`=`), not 43 (`+`).  This appears to be a system-wide design, in that Mac OS X itself interprets `CMD+SHIFT+=` as `=` plus two modifiers, not `+` and `COMMAND`.

I put together a simple jsFiddle to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/ScuDj/1/

Basically, you are going to have to deal with keyboard layouts if you want to detect `COMMAND +`.

Alternatively, you could only support the numeric keypad `+` - that works consistently! (just kidding ;-)

(Also: I tried to attach to the `textInput` event, but couldn't get it to register globally.  I think it only works on domNodes.  I've not really used that event much.)