# Intercepting CMD+Z, CMD+SHIFT+Z and CMD+Y in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events, keydown

I'm helping a company debug some problems with their undo/redo functionality in a WYSIWYG editor. Unfortunately Safari seems to gobble the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> keystroke and it never gets to the keydown callback.

Is there a way to detect these keystrokes in Javascript and prevent the default action? (the editor has its own undo/redo stack).

**Update**

Sorry I should say that I can intercept <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> when the browsers native undo stack is empty, or when the input or contenteditable isn't in focus. Otherwise it doesn't seem to be triggered or bubbled.

Comment: Detecting, yes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251956/detecting-command-keystroke-in-safari/7252716#7252716). Preventing, probably not.

Comment: I've found this project that works to capture cmd+z and can block it bubbling: https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap Unfortunately I've not been able to decipher how it succeeds so far so I can pull in just the bit that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a weird situation. The original code I had wasn't preventing bubbling of the events:

```
evt.preventDefault();
evt.stopPropagation();
```

When I added this in and refreshed the page, the browser was still intercepting the keystrokes.

**It was only by accident that I discovered that if I closed the browser tab and opened a new one to my test page that the browser must have reset something and now I was able to intercept and stop the default Undo/Redo functionality**:

Use the keydown event:

```
if (evt.metaKey || evt.ctrlKey) {
    switch (evt.which) {
        case 89: // redo, CMD+Y
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
            // Do your Redo stuff
            break;
        case 90:
            if (evt.shiftKey) { // redo, CMD+SHIFT+Z
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();
                // Do your Redo stuff
            } else { // undo, CMD+Z
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();
                // Do your Undo stuff
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Works a treat :)

Comment: In case folks skimmed this like me, the critical thing is to _close the browser tab_ and reopen before testing your changes. Must be some kind of Safari bug.

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` alone is sufficient to intercept Safari. The critical thing to note is that you have to do it on `keyup`, instead of keydown.

In Safari when you hit CMD-Z, the page command is run immediately, e.g. before the keydown event even begins.

Comment: I don't understand. `keyup` happens _after_ `keydown` so how would that help?